# Uploading video file using AJAX produces ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE Error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, server-side

I've the following PHP server configurations:

[image: Server Configuration]

> **NOTE:** Configurations provided in the above image are of real server and not of localhost and which values are coloured in green are maximum value options
>   provided by my server.

The video file which I'm uploading is of size: 91MB

I'm **using AJAX** to upload video files.

When I try to upload the file (of 91MB) it waits for few minutes and shows the following error:

[image: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE]

**WHAT ALL I'VE TRIED:**

- Increase the memory limit
- Increase maximum upload file size
- Tried of uploading video files of smaller sizes like 1MB, 36MB and for such sizes it works.

*I'm using pure Javascript to upload video file(s) and PHP on server side.*

I want know ***Why am I getting this Error*** and ***How can I overcome this***?

> **NOTE:** The script was tested in real server, and not on localhost.

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184541/3227403)? Scroll down maybe one of the lower answers applies to you. The accepted one looks not like your solution!

Comment: No none of the answer from that question help's me out :), and as I've expressed in the question I've already the `max_upload_size` and `post_max_size` and etc.. to their maximum values provided by my server.

Comment: print something or give some response text from your file upload code

Comment: @TarangP That is not the context of my question, yes I do agree even in the article which you've linked is about `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` but that is not my case ;) I'm getting this error while uploading a video and not when accessing or logging in.

Comment: @bharatsavani I've given a response code, which returns '1' when uploaded to my actual folder but it is not working!

Comment: @AkhilMK then put any condition if 1 is not return and then return anything else like 0 or false

Comment: @bharatsavani I've captured almost every scenario for which error might occur.